# WPF Popup steals focus from owner

Tags: wpf, popup

We have a WPF popup that is working perfectly except that when it opens it takes the focus from the window that triggered it which has a jarring effect as the color changes (to represent being inactive). Is there any way to alter this behavior? Or is there an easy way to disable the focus visual style only in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Well if I recall it correctly, you could set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the root element of your popup to `false`. E.g.

```xml
<Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <!-- all childs cannot get focus -->
</Grid>
```

At least in Silverlight, this was a proper workaround.

Comment: Ahh, I should have mentioned that the popup contains controls (buttons) that can be interacted with; It's not just an info popup. Otherwise this would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be able to navigate to your PopUp buttons with the keyboard you can set Focusable="False" on the Popup. This will still allow you to click on the buttons, but as I say, navigating to the buttons with the keyboard will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Popup` and override `OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus` to prevent the popup gaining focus:

```cs
protected override void OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Disallow the popup to gain focus
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This seems to work well for my purposes.